# Error when I enter xcode

Tags: xcode, uikit, xcode6

When I haven't inputted any code, I keep getting an error:

"cannot load underlying module for UIKit"

I can clean and build, and it still runs, but why does the error appear and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Are you using Swift, or Objective-C?

Comment: Using Swift. @GregHewgill

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue.  I restarted Xcode and the error went away.  Hope this is just as easy for you.